# non deterministic algorithm always find the right solution?

Tags: np

i'm confused since i see some books mention the NP time algorithms as "very lucky" that means it always finds the right path? also can someone explain the coming points to me please...

---

A nondeterministic computation is viewed as:
(i) when a choice point is reached, an infallible oracle can be
consulted to determine the right option.
(ii) When a choice point is reached, all choices are made and
computation can proceed simultaneously.

**thank you in advance , i kinda need to get clear about what NP is about**

Comment: This is off-topic for this site. Please read [tour] and [help/on-topic]. It might be suitable for [cs.se] which has a broader scope.

Comment: A nondeterministic algorithm is an algorithm in which choices are left open; they will need to be made while executing and the algorithm doesn't tell you how. Such an algorithm is said to accept a string it it reaches an accepting state for certain combinations of choices. It's not the algorithm, but the combination of choices made when executing it that needs to be "lucky" in order to end up in an accepting state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are true: if you try all the paths or just the right one, in the end you'll have the same result.

Comment: thank you i guess i just needed that , your simple answer clarified it for me , i was so confused

Comment: Please don't answer clearly off-topic question.